# Bash if condition to check if a ubuntu package needs an upgrade?

Tags: bash, apt, dpkg

I need a bash line to check if a ubuntu package needs an upgrade or not.

For example, I want to check if the package 'firefox' needs an upgrade using dpkg or apt-get commands.

Hypthetical Example:

```
# Hypothetical example pseudo-code
if [[ $(firefox_needs_upgrade) ]]; then echo "Firefox needs upgrading";fi
```

Answer (score 2):

```
##Simulate an upgrade and grep for the firefox package
##Feel free to replace ' firefox' with something more specific

RET=apt-get -s upgrade | grep firefox
if [ $ret -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "I don't have access to a debian box right now"
fi
```

From: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19470/list-available-updates-but-do-not-install-them

Comment: Doesn't work correctly. What if there is a package named "firefox-utils"

Comment: I don't have access to a debian machine... "##Feel free to replace ' firefox' with something more specific" You may have to do some leg work on your own.

Comment: No, I meant if you provide "firefox", it might also match a package named "firefox-utils" (hypothetically). In a case where "firefox" package is up-to-date but firefox-utils needs upgrading, this will give a false positive.

Answer (score 0):

You can check version of programs installed under apt with command:

```
 dpkg -l
```

You can check a current package by referencing the [Ubuntu Packages Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/). Alternatively, for any package under apt (assuming that you have the updates repository enabled), you can use the apt-get command to update your package information and check for upgrades:

```
 apt-get update
 apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If you are not logged in as root (which is generally to be avoided, you may have to use sudo to have sufficient privileges):

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Check the apt-get [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/apt-get.8.html) for more options.

Finally, you can search (or subscribe to) [Ubuntu security notices](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/) to keep yourself notified real-time of needed updates.

Comment: So in bash, how can I check if firefox is up-to-date or not using dpkg?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't read that exactly right. In any case (whether automatic updating is a good idea or not), here is the [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates) for doing this with the GNOME Update Manager, the unattended-upgrades package, by writing your own cron script that calls aptitude, or using cron-apt.

Comment: I'm looking to write an if condition in a bash script, eg. if [ $(firefox_needs_updating) ]; then echo 'You need to update firefox'

Answer (score 0):

The command your looking for is `apt list --upgradable 2>/dev/null`.

And using it in your example:

```sh
package_name=firefox
if [[ $(apt list --upgradable 2>/dev/null  | grep $package_name) ]]; then echo "${package_name} needs upgrading";fi
```

Note: `2>/dev/null` is used to suppress the warning message from `apt`

Answer (score -2):

Try to use apticron

```
apt-get install apticron
```

After installation configure it here:

> /etc/apticron/apticron.conf

It will give you a daily notification on mail if anything need to be updated.

Comment: I'm looking for a bash if condition. eg. if [[ $(firefox_needs_updated) ]] // do something